# Using LINQ C# to calculate MTBF

Tags: c#, linq

My data is listed in the following format, (the time values are the same, used for sample)

```
 ID Result      StartTime                EndTime
 1  Fail    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 2  Fail    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 3  Pass    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 4  Fail    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 5  Fail    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 6  Pass    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 7  Fail    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 8  Pass    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 9  pass    4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
 10  pass   4/2/2013 1:17:29 PM     4/2/2013 1:19:30 PM
```

I have to find the MTBF for this using ∑ (T1,T2,…Tn) / n where n is the numebr of failures and T1,T2,…Tn refers to the uptime before the occurence of a failure. As of now, I have been able to calculate the elapsed time for each iteration,

```
using (DatabaseEntities entities = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    var result = entities.ExecutionDetails.Select(p => p);
    foreach (var p in result)
    {
        if (p.StartTime.HasValue && p.EndTime.HasValue)
        {
            var duration = (p.EndTime.Value - p.StartTime.Value).ToString("c");
            Console.WriteLine("Duration" + duration);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me find the right approach and queries to use to capture the related data in order to calculate MTBF.
Thanks.

Updated Code

```
var results = entities.TestExecutionDetails.ToList();

            var failures = results.Where(p => p.Result == "Fail").Select(p => p); 

            foreach(var p in failures)
            {
             if (p.StartTime.HasValue && p.EndTime.HasValue)
             {

                 var elapsedduration = elapsedduration + (p.EndTime.Value - p.StartTime.Value).ToString("c");

             }

             var mtbf = elapsedduration / failures.Count();
```

Final Update

```
            TimeSpan elaspsedduration = new TimeSpan(0);
             ........
              .....
             foreach (var p in uptime)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Uptime is" + uptime);
                if (p.StartTime.HasValue && p.EndTime.HasValue)
                {
                    elaspsedduration += (p.EndTime.Value - p.StartTime.Value);
                }
             var mtbf = elaspsedduration.TotalSeconds / failures;

            Console.WriteLine("MTBF Value is " + mtbf);
```

Comment: MTBF: Mean Time Between Failures?

Comment: Yes, Mean Time Between Failures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something similar to this will probably do the job.

```
var results = entities.ExecutionDetails.ToList();

var failures = results.Where(p => p.Result == "Fail");

var sigmaDiff = failures.Sum(p => p.EndTime.Subtract(p.StartTime));

var mtbf = sigmaDiff/failures.Count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have modified the code, based on your input. Can you pls help me fix the error that I'm gettign now, "Cannot use local variable elapsed duration before it is declared."

Comment: It sounds like the variable 'elapsed_duration' had not been declared or initialised. Does this variable exist in your method and have you given it a value?

Comment: I need to find the sum of the time differences, thats what I am trying to do, if i set var elapsedduration = 0 at the beginning, i get the exceptio, DbArithmetic expression arguments must have numeric common type.